# Locate two variable strings and write one as a file

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, sed

I have a text document that contains 2 lines of information.  Line 1 contains a filename, and line 2 contains an reference ID.  The document contains additional strings other than the desired information and I'm trying to come up with a non-cluttered way to collect only the information that I desire.  Using 'cut -d' a bunch of times seems sloppy.

Here is an example of my data

```
12:"content":"file;\r\n\tfilename=\"TestingFile.txt"} 
13-"refid":"9B46BCAEDC9923"}]
```

Using that information, I want to create a file called TestingFile.txt and write the refid value as the contents -- basically the values between the " " and nothing more.

**tfilename=\"**  and **refid":"**  will always precede the data I'm looking to grab, and there will always be a few characters following the final **"** on the line.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'"' 'NR==1 {fname=$(NF-1);} NR==2{print $(NF-1) >fname;}' file
```

#### Explanation

`awk` implicitly loops through every line of a file.  Each line is divided into fields.

- `-F'"'`

  This makes the a double-quote character function as the field separator.  Looking at the sample input, that means that the fields that we want will be the second to last on each line
- `NR==1 {fname=$(NF-1);}`

  The first line has the filename.  In `awk`, `NF` is the number of fields on a line.  So, `$(NF-1)` references the second to last field.  Its content is saved into the variable `fname`.
- `NR==2{print $(NF-1) >fname;}`

  The second line has the ID as its second to last field.  We `print` this ID to a file named `fname`.

#### Example

If the above code is run against the sample input, a file `TestingFile.txt` is created in the current directory:

```
$ cat TestingFile.txt
9B46BCAEDC9923
```

#### More complex input

Suppose that the input file looks like:

```
12:"content":"file;\r\n\tfilename=\"TestingFile.txt","date":"2014-10-23"} 
13-"refid":"9B46BCAEDC9923","author":"Anon"}]
```

Since our data will no longer be the second to last fields, we need to change the `awk` code:

```
awk -F'"' 'NR==1 {sub(/.*tfilename=\\"/, "");fname=$1;} NR==2 {sub(/.*refid":"/,"");print $1>fname;}' file2
```

This code removes all characters before the filename (line 1) or ID (line 2).  Once this has been done, the information that we want will be in field 1.  The code is otherwise the same.

Comment: That is a really good example and explanation.  Thank you.  But, what if it's not always the 2nd field from the last?  Sometimes there may be additional fields other than the ones listed.  I always know the preceding data, but not necessarily all of the data after the "

Comment: @BeMyFriend That is probably easily handled.  So I can be sure what you mean, would you provide a sample of such input?  For example, would the first line include the characters `\"TestingFile.txt"` or else would it look like `\"TestingFile.txt\"`?

Comment: @BeMyFriend I made a guess at your input format.  See updated answer. Let me know.